# Sitecore file upload event

Tags: sitecore

I need to itercept event when user uploads file into file drop area.

In this event I should have access to item that has file drop area and file that has been uploaded.

I tried item:saved and uiUpload processor but they don't provide enough information.

What I need is:

- File drop area field ID
- Upadete item
- Uploaded file name

Do sitecore have event for such kind of user action with all required information?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to resolve my problem.

I used uiUpload pipeline to intercept file upload.

Then I used UploadedItems property of UploadArgs to get document item in media library.

After that I used media folder property "Refererrs" (it's item ancestor with FDAFolder template) to get related item and field which is uploaded to.